# Match string with 2 or 3 hyphens with filetype (regex)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches strings with 2 or 3 hyphens, followed by a filetype. So far I can't generalize this to make it work for either case; any help would be fantastic.

About the strings:

• The first character of every hyphen-delimited substring will be capitalized.

• Each substring will be 2 or more characters long.

• The filetype will be 3 or 4 characters long.

This is what I've been able to come up with:
[A-Z][a-z]{2,}-[A-Z][a-z]{2,}.[a-z]{3,4}

Comment: Try [`^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+){1,2}\.[a-z]{3,4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/0XYUCx/1). Don't you want to include chars like digits at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to add another letter character group with the `?` option which says 0 or 1 of the preceding parenthesized group can be present. You also forgot to escape the `.` which represents any single character normally. This regex should match what you are asking for:

`^[A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+(-[A-Z][a-z]+)?\.[a-z]{3,4}$`.

However, keep in mind that file extensions can sometimes have numbers in them, for example `.bz2`. Unless you have direct control over the file extensions, I would use this instead:

`^[A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+(-[A-Z][a-z]+)?\.[a-z0-9]{3,4}$`.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, we've got control over the filetypes, they aren't alphanumeric. (Only .xlxs, .txt, etc.)